# How to return a string, not a Promise in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want the function to wait for the string and return it because it's one of the first things that appear on the web page, otherwise it'd let it blank. 
the getCompte(mat): string {...} function always returns that 'test' and skips the first instruction, I tried async-await but it forces me to return a promise again.. how can I return this string?

in the component :

```
getCompte(mat: number): string {
    this.compteService.getCompte(mat).then( res => {
      console.log('haho :' + res);
      return  res;
    });
    return 'test';
  }
```

in the service :

```
async getCompte(mat: number): Promise<string> {
    return await new Promise(resolve => {this.http.get<Compte[]>('http://localhost:3000/comptes').subscribe(res => {
      res.forEach(element => {
        if (element.mat === mat) {
          resolve(element.nom);
        }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I expect the output to be that element. nom, but the actual output is 'test'.

Comment: Once control returns to the code that handles the promise response, the code has already returned (`return 'test';`), the caller has already moved on with its life; where would `return res;` return to?

Comment: Youcef, you're trying to use an asynchronous paradigm in a synchronous way. You cannot "return" anything from inside a Promise or Reactive function since it executes in a completely separate context. Also I don't think you can force it with async/await either. Whatever is dependent on an answer from `getCompte` needs to forget that it will return one and instead wait for `getCompte` to set a variable or `getCompte` might need to call a function that tells the component that it is done and provides that with the answer (more preferred option). That's how traditional async programming works.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a variable in the component class like `text: string`. Once the `Promise` is returned, then set the response to the variable.

```
text: string;
getCompte(mat: number): void {
    this.compteService.getCompte(mat).then( res => {
        this.text = res as string;
    });

}
```

Comment: thanks, but this function is used dynamically on array elements, i cant create a string for every element.

Comment: convert text into an array and push every time the response comes back?

Answer (score 0):

why not add a preloader until you get the actual output or else

create a subject and register to it rather then returning test, for example in service

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }// from @angular/core/http i guess not selenium one



 compte = new Subject<[]>();

    getCompteObs() {
       return this.compte.asObservable();
    }

    getCompte(mat: number) {

let comptes = [];

    this.http.get<compute[]>('http://localhost:3000/comptes').subscribe(res => {
          res.forEach(el => {
           this.comptes.push(el);
           });
         this.compute.next(comptes);
        });
      }
```

inside component -

implement OnInit Interface and inside the class

```
class abc implement OnInit() {

let recCon = []; //initially empty add preloader

constructor(public comptService: ComptService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.comptService.getCompte(// pass mat: number);
  this.recCon = this.comptService.getCompteObs.subscribe(res => {
   this.recCon = res as [];
})
}

}
```

i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Why using observables when not really needing it. You can use instead a simple fetch:

in the component :

```
getCompte(mat: number): string {
    const comptes = await this.compteService.getCompte(mat);
  }
```

in the service :

```
async getCompte(mat: number): Promise<any> {
    return await fetch('http://localhost:3000/comptes')
                      .then(response => response.json());
  }
```

Comment: hi thanks, an async function must return a Promise.. that's why i can't find a solution to this

Comment: I tried it, and it says : The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.ts(1064)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your service like the following :

```
getCompte():Promise<any> {
  return  this.http.get<compute[]>('http://localhost:3000/comptes').toPromise();
}
```

And in your component, define a variable as below (to hold the result):

```
public result: string= null;
```

Then in your method:

```
getCompte(mat: number): string {
   this.compteService.getCompte()
     .then(response=> {
        response.forEach(element => {
            if (element.mat === mat) {
                return element.nom
            }
        });
     })
     .then(response=> {
         this.result= response ? response : 'test';      
     });
}
```

Comment: thanks, but since all this code is in the .then(response=> {...}. it will still tell me this : A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value (about getCompte, it can be fixed by adding return 'test' at the end, but it'll still return it anyways :/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't involve promises here at all, if it is not a requirement. HttpClient returns an observable, so let's just embrace that :)

You can then in your component either manually subscribe or use the `async` pipe to display your value.

So based on the above I suggest the following (using `async` pipe):

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

getCompte(mat: number): Observable<string> {
  return this.http.get<Compte[]>('http://localhost:3000/comptes').pipe(
    map(res => {
      const match = res.find(r => r.mat === mat);
      return match ? match.nom : null
    })
  )
}
```

Component:

```ts
recon$: Observable<string> 

ngOnInit() {
  this.recon$ = this.comptService.getCompte(// pass mat: number);
}
```

Then you can display this using async pipe in view:

```html
<p *ngIf="(recon$ | async) as recon">{{recon}}</p>
```